# How to use the File-Open dll in visual studio (Basic) and redirect it to the associated program for it's file type

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, basic

The title pretty much says it all. I want to make my program able to send, say, a .Docx or .html to the correct program using the filetype associations in Windows. If all this is asking far too much on a forum (Which even I realize it probably is), how do I at least access the dll for the File-open Command?

*Edit*

I'm trying to get the examples suggested below to work, but I always get the same error at the Declare: Statement is not valid inside a method/multiline Lambda

What do I do from here?

Comment: Have you tried ShellExecute? See this MS article for help/information and an example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170918 . The example should be easily adaptable to VB .Net

Comment: As well there is VB .Net info here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.shellexecute  with an example that should do the trick